# Laravel Passing Parameters in URL

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a webhook in a website, so that when a certain action is performed, one of my functions in my Laravel app is executed with the PUT method. The webhook has the following url to execute `app.myapp.com/sync/documents/gt?salesID=12345`.

How do I receive this parameter in Laravel?

This is my route:

```
Route::put('/sync/vendus/documents/gt', 'SyncController@postVendusGT');
```

And then in my method I have:

```
public function postVendusGT($request){
    dd($request->salesID);
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

`Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\SyncController::postVendusGT()`

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to inject the request object, this means adding the type. This tells Laravel the first parameter has to be a request object and not an url parameter.

```
public function postVendusGT(Request $request) {
    dd($request->salesID);
}
```

More information can be found in [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#accessing-the-request).

Comment: I was just coming here to write an answer because I just realized what I was missing xp Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider marking this as the answer so people with the same problem will find the solution here. :)

Answer (score 4):

You have to type-hint `$request`

```
public function postVendusGT(Request $request)
```

Answer (score 1):

Offering this as a couple of alternatives:

```
public function postVendusGT(){
    dd(\Request::get("salesID"));
}
```

or

```
public function postVendusGT(){
    $request = resolve('request');
    dd($request->salesID);
}
```

Just in case dependency injection is not possible in a given scenario.